# Laravel subdomains routing and session management

Tags: laravel-5, routes, subdomain

I am trying to set an isolated backend and frontend environments in the same Laravel5 application.

My ideal purpose is to get such isolation thru

- subdomains
- different guards(tables) for users at front and users at    backend

Up now I've  just defined my guard/providers at config/auth.php 
and done :

**Routing**

```
    Route::group(['domain' => 'front.mydomain.com'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

        Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
                Route::auth();
        });


        Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {
                Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

                Route::group(['prefix' => 'record'], function () {
                        Route::get('all','RecordController@all');
                });
        });     
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.mydomain.com'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

        Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
                //SOLO RUTAS de pantallas de LOGIN
                Route::get('/password/reset', function() { 
                        return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404);
                });     
                Route::auth();
        });

        Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth:admin']], function () {
                Route::get('/home', function() {
                        return  view('admin.dashboard');
                });

                Route::group(['prefix' => 'record'], function () {
                        Route::get('all', 'RecordController@all');
                        Route::get('edit/{id}', 'RecordController@edit')->where('id','[0-9]+');
                });
        });
});
```

**Config/session (extract)**

```
'domain' => '.urbina.biz',
```

I was expecting to get errors because I haven't yet implemented model/tables for the admin part, BUT all I get is redirection loops , apparently because the cookie is not really isolating my subdomains, looks like it's mixing it all up :(

Some one may help ?

Comment: More to clarify my problem. Steps to rise the redirection loop :

[1].- Login to the front.mydomain.com (Ok!)
[2].- Try to login to admin.mydomain.com ==> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
[3] .-Now both subdomains responses are ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS until i remove cookies

Comment: Ok, probably followed this issue in laracast : https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/laravel/setup-different-frontend-backend-endpoints-in-laravel-51

Comment: At least I solved it. Just follow my posts and conversation with @firewizard at  https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/laravel/setup-different-frontend-backend-endpoints-in-laravel-51.  I cannot detail here as comments do not accept markdown and cannot reply my self :(